# How to convert and compare byte array to int

Tags: arrays, c, integer, byte

I'm trying to compare a byte array with a hex number, having a surprisingly hard time.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int bytes[4] = { 0x7c, 0x71, 0xde, 0xbb };
    int number = 0x7c71debb;
    
    printf("%u\n", number);
    printf("%u\n", (int)*bytes);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting:

```
2087837371
124
```

I did some reading and I tried using `memcpy` as suggested in various places:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int bytes[4] = { 0x7c, 0x71, 0xde, 0xbb };
    int number = 0x7c71debb;
    
    int frombytes;
    
    memcpy(&frombytes, bytes, 4);
    
    printf("%u\n", number);
    printf("%u\n", frombytes);

    return 0;
}
```

Still the same result:

```
2087837371
124
```

I mean, it's been like an hour if I got to be honest frustration is starting to get a hold of me.

It all started from me trying to do this:

```
if ((unsigned int)bytes == 0x7c71debb)
```

EDIT:

After switching bytes' type to char or uint8_t, here's what I'm getting:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint8_t bytes[4] = { 0x7c, 0x71, 0xde, 0xbb };
    int number = 0x7c71debb;
    
    int frombytes;
    
    memcpy(&frombytes, bytes, 4);
    
    printf("%u\n", number);
    printf("%u\n", (int)*bytes);
    printf("%u\n", frombytes);

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
2087837371
124
3151917436
```

Comment: Your bytes are not actual bytes, theyre integers, and probably 32-bit integers:

char bytes[4] = { 0x7c, 0x71, 0xde, 0xbb }; 

would be bytes.

Comment: Also, have you looked into using unions for this issue? You could make a union of a 32 bit integer and an array of 4 bytes, or a 64 bit integer and an array of 8 bytes.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I switched bytes to uint8_t and I'm now getting different results, gonna add them to the question.

Comment: Step 1, Use `"%x"` rather than `"%u"`..

Comment: If you check the hexadecmal representation of your two large numbers you'll see:
3151917436 -> 0xBBDE717C   and   
2087837371 -> 0x7C71DEBB

Comment: As a side note `int` is the wrong type since it can't contain raw values of 0x80000000 or larger. Use `uint32_t`.

Comment: @Lundin How presumptuous of you to claim the OP is wrong about the number being a signed number without any basis to indicate an error. Yes, 80 00 00 00 could mean 2,147,483,648, but there's no reason to disbelieve that it means -2,147,483,648

Comment: @ikegami Either it's a signed number and if so it should be assigned a decimal base value. Or it's an unsigned number and then using a 32 bit hex constant is fine.

Comment: @ikegami Also the way C's subtly dysfunctional type system works, the hex constant `0x80000000` always means 2,147,483,648 and never -2,147,483,648. Should we write `int number = 0x80000000;` then an implementation-defined conversion from `unsigned int` to  `int` occurs and a conforming implementation is allowed to toss a `signal` at you when that happens. Just don't write programs relying on implicit, subtle conversions.

Comment: @Lundin, He doesn't have 0x80000000, In the hypothetical, he would have `uint8_t bytes[4] = { 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };` Yes that could mean 2,147,483,648, but it could also mean -2,147,483,648. There's no reason to believe `int32_t` is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making two assumptions:

- You're assuming `int` is exactly 32 bits in size.

  This might be correct, but it could be smaller or larger. You should use `int32_t` or `uint32_t` instead.
- You're assuming a [big-endian machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

  If you are using an x86 or x86_64, this is incorrect. These are little-endian architectures. The bytes are ordered from least-significant to most-significant.

The following code avoids those assumptions:

```c
int32_t frombytes =
   (uint32_t)bytes[0] << ( 8 * 3 ) |
   (uint32_t)bytes[1] << ( 8 * 2 ) |
   (uint32_t)bytes[2] << ( 8 * 1 ) |
   (uint32_t)bytes[3] << ( 8 * 0 );
```

(It looks a bit expensive, but your compiler should optimize this.)

Comment: Yeah that crossed my mind but I guess I'm just burned out at this point. Thanks!

Comment: There's also the assumption that the representation for negatives is the same for both systems. But everyone uses two's complement these days, so I'm leaving it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can build the int using bitwise operators on the array values.

The below code, which assumes big-endian architecture and ints that are at least 4 bytes long, outputs:

```
2087837371
2087837371
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int bytes[4] = { 0x7c, 0x71, 0xde, 0xbb };
    int number = 0x7c71debb;
    int number2 = bytes[3] | bytes[2] << 8 | bytes[1] << 16 | bytes[0] << 24;
    
    printf("%u\n", number);
    printf("%u\n", number2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's what I just tried out, thanks for the help!

Comment: Note: This won't work if `int` is larger or smaller than 32 bits.

Comment: Except if `bytes[0]` happens to be 0x80 or larger, then this code invokes undefined behavior. Just don't use `int` for bitwise arithmetic ever.

Comment: @ikegami Or if `int` is exactly 32 bits and we left shift a value 0x80 or larger by 24 into the sign bit.

Comment: @Lundin, True. It's wrong no matter what size `int` is.